# LDAP - Active Directory Error Codes - Receive Error 52e instead of 773

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We are attempting to login to `Active Directory` using `Spring-LDAP-1.3.1-RELEASE` version, with a user who has an account option set `User must change password at next logon`.

The problem is that a `52e` (invalid credentials) is returned, instead of the `773` error code (user must reset password).  The exception is throw as is from the `AD` server and printed out in the `org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException` class.  The exact exception is:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

Has anyone had a similar issue where a `52e` is returned from `Active Directory`, when it should be returning a `773`?

A list of the error codes can be found here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631